# PySpark: TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm loading data from HDFS, which I want to filter by specific variables. But somehow the Column.isin command does not work. It throws this error:

> TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col
variables = ('852-PI-769', '812-HC-037', '852-PC-571-OUT')
df = sqlContext.read.option("mergeSchema", "true").parquet("parameters.parquet")
same_var = col("Variable").isin(variables)
df2 = df.filter(same_var)
```

The schema looks like this:

```
df.printSchema()
root
 |-- Time: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- Value: float (nullable = true)
 |-- Variable: string (nullable = true)
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong? PS: It's Spark 1.4 with Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: The `x object is not a callable` means that `x` is not a function yet you try to call `x()`. My guess (as I have no knowlegde on spark) is that either `col` is not the right name for the function you want or that it is used with a different syntax maybe `x[]` or so ...

Comment: I figured out that Spark 1.4. used "in" instead of the newer "isin" but nevertheless it still doesn't work.

Comment: df.filter(df.Variable.isin(variables))

Comment: Nope, does not work. It's the same error and my code above is actually doing the same.

Comment: Could you solve it? I have a similar Problem :/

Comment: No, not yet solved :(

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: @Donbeo finally, there is an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `isin` was added to Spark in version 1.5.0 and therefore not yet avaiable in your version of Spark as seen in the documentation of `isin` [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.isin).

There is a similar function [`in`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#in(scala.collection.Seq)) in the Scala API that was introduced in 1.3.0 which has a similar functionality (there are some differences in the input since `in` only accepts columns). In PySpark this function is called [`inSet`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.inSet)instead. Usage examples from the documentation:

> ```
> df[df.name.inSet("Bob", "Mike")]
> df[df.age.inSet([1, 2, 3])]
> ```

**Note**: `inSet` is depricated in version 1.5.0 and forward, `isin` should be used in newer versions.

Comment: This might be true. Unfortunately I don’t have access to that cluster anymore. But I really doubt that the spark version was that old. Usually it was up to date.

Comment: @Matthias: The version should be correct (it's actually in the question itself). The question is a bit old but thought I'd leave an answer here in hope it can help someone with similar problems in the future (issues with functions introduced in newer versions)

Comment: This question was open for quite a long time. Thanks for the final answer now :)

Comment: @Matthias: No problems. Hopefully it will be helpful to someone :)

Answer (score -1):

Please use the below code to check

```
df.filter(df.Variable.isin(['852-PI-769', '812-HC-037', '852-PC-571-OUT']))
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15237115)

Comment: @CodeMouse92 A code-only answer might not be a good one, but it's still an answer. I would recommend you this post about the LQPRQ: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)

Comment: @FelixSFD I already follow those patterns, and have a separate "code only" comment (after which point I click Looks Ok) - this did not seem to answer the question at all, but rather be a comment, which is why I marked it as I did.